# WordPress Cookie Issue (Only Sets if Admin)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies

I am using an ID to set a cookie value. It only works if I am logged in as an adminstrator in WordPress.  It will set for non-logged in users, but only if they are on the home page.

Here is the link to set the cookie:

```
<a id="fl-es-link" href="Link Name"></a>
```

Here is the script I'm using. I'm guessing that this script deletes the value then reassigns it. (I think) - Like I mentioned - it works on any page in any browser for admins, but only on the home page for non-admins.

```
$(function(){
$("#fl-es-link").click(function() {
jQuery.cookie("language", null, { path: '/' });
jQuery.cookie('language', 'Texas', { path: '/', domain: 'domain.com', expires: 365 });
   });
```

});

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is really confusing. Can you describe exactly what you want to happen and then what part of that isn't happening with this code? Where is this function located?

Comment: It's on every page of the website.  There are actually two links.  If a link is clicked, the cookie value need to change.  Each link is for either English or Spanish.  If I am logged in as a WordPress admin, it works every time.

If I'm not an admin, it only works on the root page of the website.  Hope this helps.